# Memory Leakage while using dynamic array pointer in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic, memory-leaks

As the title reads, I get memory leakage when I run my program. However, I think the problem is that I do not tell the destructor to free all of the memory when the program is done. But the problem is that the program crashes when I try to put my freeMemory() function in the destructor. The compiler says that the function getString() in my base class could not read from string. I wonder if you can see the problem, because I surely can not... And to not get too many rows of code, I will only post the functions which could be the possible source of leakage. Handler.h:

```
class Handler {
private:
    Competitor* *person;
    int capacity;
    int nrOfCompetitors;
    void expand();
    void initiate(int start) const;
    int find(string name) const;
    void freeMemory();
public:
    Handler(int capacity = 3);
    Handler(const Handler & origObj);
    virtual ~Handler();
    Handler operator=(const Handler & origObj);
    bool addExerciser(string name, string gender, int age);
    bool addProffs(string name, string gender, string compound, int nrOfSeasons);
    void getCompetitors(string arr[]) const;
    int getNrOfCompetitors() const;
    void getProffs(string arr[]) const;
    int getNrOfProffs() const;
    void getExercisers(string arr[]) const;
    int getNrOfExercisers() const;
    bool removeCompetitor(string name);
    bool changeNrOfSeasons(string name, int newNrOfSeasons) const;
    void sortCompetitors();
};
```

Handler.cpp (just the relevant functions):

```
void Handler::expand() {
    this->capacity += 5;
    Competitor* *tmp = new Competitor*[capacity];

    for (int i = 0; i < this->nrOfCompetitors; i++) {
        tmp[i] = this->person[i];
    }
    delete[] this->person;

    this->person = tmp;
    this->initiate(nrOfCompetitors);
}

void Handler::initiate(int start) const {
    for (int i = start; i < this->capacity; i++) {
        person[i] = nullptr;
    }
}

void Handler::freeMemory() {
    for (int i = 0; i < nrOfCompetitors; i++) {
        delete person[i];
    }
    delete[] person;
}

Handler::Handler(int capacity) {
    this->capacity = capacity;
    this->nrOfCompetitors = 0;
    this->person = new Competitor*[this->capacity];
    initiate(0);
}

Handler::Handler(const Handler & origObj) {
    this->capacity = origObj.capacity;
    this->nrOfCompetitors = origObj.nrOfCompetitors;
    this->person = new Competitor*[origObj.capacity];
    for (int i = 0; i < this->capacity; i++) {
        person[i] = origObj.person[i];
    }
    initiate(nrOfCompetitors);
}

Handler::~Handler() {
    //freeMemory();
    delete[] person;
}

Handler Handler::operator=(const Handler & origObj) {
    if (this != &origObj) {
        freeMemory();
        this->capacity = origObj.capacity;
        this->nrOfCompetitors = origObj.nrOfCompetitors;
        this->person = new Competitor*[origObj.capacity];
        for (int i = 0; i < this->capacity; i++) {
            person[i] = origObj.person[i];
        }
        initiate(nrOfCompetitors);
    }
    return *this;
}

bool Handler::removeCompetitor(string name) {
    bool removed = false;
    int found = find(name);

    if (found != -1) {
        delete person[found];
        for (int i = found; i < nrOfCompetitors; i++) {
            person[found] = person[found + 1];
        }
        delete person[nrOfCompetitors];
        nrOfCompetitors -= 1;
        removed = true;
    }

    return removed;
}

void Handler::sortCompetitors() {
    Competitor* tmp;
    bool swap;

    do {
        swap = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < nrOfCompetitors - 1; i++) {
            if (person[i]->getName() > person[i + 1]->getName()) {
                tmp = person[i];
                person[i] = person[i + 1];
                person[i + 1] = tmp;
                swap = true;
            }
        }
    } while (swap);
}
```

EDIT:
When the program crashes while I am trying to use the freeMemory() function in my destructor, the compiler says that the getString() function in my base class could not read character from string.

Competitor.h (base class):

```
string getString() const;
virtual string getSpecificString() const = 0;
```

Competitor.cpp:

```
string Deltagare::getString() const {
    return "Name: " + this->name + "\nGender: " + this->gender + "\n" + this->getSpecificString();
}
```

Exerciser.h (sub class):

```
virtual string getSpecificString() const;
```

Exerciser.cpp

```
string Exerciser::getSpecificString() const {
    return "Age: " + to_string(this->age);
}
```

Solved! Solution:
The problems were in the destructor, assignment operator and the copy-constructor, but they are fixed now. I used a clone method because I was not able to type person[i] = new Competitor[origObj.person[i]] because of the fact that the Competitor class is an abstract class.

Competitor.h:

```
virtual Competitor* clone() const = 0;
```

Exerciser.h:

```
Exerciser* clone() const;
```

Exerciser.cpp:

```
Exerciser * Exerciser::clone() const {
    return new Exerciser(*this);
}
```

Edit in the copy-constructor and the assignment operator:

```
this->person = new Competitor*[origObj.capacity];
    for (int i = 0; i < origObj.nrOfCompetitors; i++) {
        person[i] = origObj.person[i]->clone();
    }
```

Edit in the destructor:

```
Handler::~Handler() {
    freeMemory();
}
```

Comment: Why did you comment out the `freeMemory` call in the destructor? That indeed seems like something that could lead to leaks.

Comment: Perhaps using `std::vector` will overcome the problems.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I wrote that the program is crashing when I am using it. But yeah, it is probably the leak. The second problem is to find out why the program crashes x/

Comment: The reason your `freeMemory` function crashing is most likely because you don't do a deep copy in the copy-constructor. You allocate memory only for the `person` array, but the actual `Competitor` pointers in the array are copied, meaning you will have multiple object having the same pointers. You need to actually copy the `Competitor` *objects*. The simple solution is to use `std::vector<Competitor>` instead of your manual memory handling. No pointers needed. Then you can also use the default copy-constructor, assignment operator *and* destructor.

Comment: There are also issues in `removeCompetitor`.

Comment: Okey thank you! Yes the problems were in the destructor, assignment operator and the copy-construtor, but they are fixed now. I used a clone method because I was not able to type person[i] = new Competitor[origObj.person[i]] because of the fact that the Competitor class is an abstract class. I will post my solution as an edit if anyone is interested.

Comment: Don't use raw pointers. Use std containers and/or smart pointers.